# PHP explode specific text beetwen different elements

Tags: php, explode

I have result

```
{"success":true,"data":{"id":6583879,"listingId":"11745/3470/OMS"}}
```

I need to explode it on two arrays:

```
$id = 6583879;
```

and

```
$listid = 11745/3470/OMS
```

I'd like to avoid counting characters, this response may be another in future. I was thinking about taking:

- everything between "id": and comma
- everything between "listingId":" and "

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[**PHP code demo**](https://eval.in/766545)

```
<?php
$json='{"success":true,"data":{"id":6583879,"listingId":"11745/3470/OMS"}}';
$array=  json_decode($json,true);
extract($array["data"]);
$first=array("id"=>$id);
$second=array("listingId"=>$listingId);
print_r($first);
print_r($second);
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [id] => 6583879
)
Array
(
    [listingId] => 11745/3470/OMS
)
```

Comment: I added 
$myid = implode(',', $first);
$listid= implode(',', $second);
echo $myid;

Comment: @ŁukaszGręźlikowski as i was mentioned in the post to have arrays thats my i added it in array

Answer (score 0):

just decode the json data

```
$data = '{"success":true,"data":[{"id":6583879,"listingId":"11745/3470/OMS"}]}';

$arr = json_decode($data);
$id = array();
$listing = array();


for($i=0; $i < count($arr->data); $i++){
    $id[$i] = $arr->data[$i]->id;
    $listing[$i] = $arr->data[$i]->listingId;
}

//loop array to view data
foreach($id as $value){
   echo $value.'<br>';
}

?>
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-‌​code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '['    on $id = []; line

Comment: did you copy paste it? it's working

Comment: wont work on php prior to 7

Comment: `$id = [];` is not working on version 5.3 and below. so i changed it to `$id = array();`. Try it again

Comment: it gives me only Array Array

Comment: dude you need to loop the array to view the data. or you can use `print_r($id);`

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$json='{"success":true,"data":{"id":6583879,"listingId":"11745/3470/OMS"}}';
$decoded = json_decode($json);
$id = $decoded['data']['id'];
$listingId = $decoded['data']['listingId'];
```